# camel cxf payload mode interceptor throws org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

I am using a CXF-Interceptor written by a colleague to add soap headers required by a third party webservice to the soap envelope of an apache camel message that was created by an xsl file. The interceptor works correctly for my colleague, on his route however on mine it fails. I copied my endpoints directly from his route, so I don't think that is the problem. I asked my colleague, and he'd never seen anything like this.

My route is:

```
<to uri="bean:applicationName?method=setBodyToBlankXML" />
<to uri="xslt:xsl/applicationName-thirdPartyWebserviceOperationName.xsl" />
<setHeader headerName="operationName">
<constant>OperationName</constant>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="operationNamespace">
<constant>thirdPartyNamespace</constant>
</setHeader>
<to uri="cxf:bean:thirdPartyWebserviceBean" />
```

His route is:

```
<to uri="bean:applicationName?method=setBodyToBlankXML" />
                        <to uri="xslt:xsl/applicationName-thirdPartyWebserviceOperationName.xsl" />
                        <log message="Display Request ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />
                        <to uri="cxf:bean:thirdPartyWebserviceBean" />
```

The Full stack trace is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.Source
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:79) ~[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.databinding.source.XMLStreamDataWriter.write(XMLStreamDataWriter.java:54) ~[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.HybridSourceDataBinding$1.write(HybridSourceDataBinding.java:100) ~[camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.HybridSourceDataBinding$1.write(HybridSourceDataBinding.java:81) ~[camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleHeaderPart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:256) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:177) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:87) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:67) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:416) [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:112) [camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.access$100(Pipeline.java:43) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline$1.done(Pipeline.java:136) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor$InternalCallback.done(CamelInternalProcessor.java:251) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MDCUnitOfWork$MDCCallback.done(MDCUnitOfWork.java:231) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$1.done(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:428) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor$1.done(InstrumentationProcessor.java:81) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$1.done(SendProcessor.java:131) [camel-core-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfClientCallback.handleResponse(CxfClientCallback.java:61) [camel-cxf-2.14.1.jar:2.14.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:819) [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1638) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1145) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428) [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353) [cxf-core-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
```

Anylzing the stack trace, it appears that the actual exception is being thrown within CXF itself. It appears that at the point the exception occured at, CXF is doing whatever internal processing it requires to send the request onwards.

There doesn't seem to be that much information about this issue on the internet, the only hit that I got was an old unanswered message in a mailing list archive.  Am I doing something wrong, could this be an obscure bug in CXF, or is there something else entirely that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

My team encountered a similar issue and I also saw that [mailing list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/please-help-with-transformation-of-a-response-by-xslt-td5756711.html)

Our solution was to use the same dataFormat for both producer and consumer.

Originally we were using dataFormat.PAYLOAD at our from("cxf:bean:") and dataFormat.RAW at our to("cxf:bean:"). Using dataFormat.PAYLOAD at both endpoints resolved the issue.